# Azure Logic App with SharePoint Connection

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, office-dev-pnp, logic-app

I am creating my first logic app which connects to SharePoint and adds entries into some sharepoint list.

Whenever I create a SharePoint Connection it adds below resource to my logic app.

```
{
  "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
  "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
  "name": "[parameters('sharepointonline_1_Connection_Name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('logicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'sharepointonline')]"
    },
    "displayName": "[parameters('sharepointonline_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
    "nonSecretParameterValues": {
      "token:TenantId": "[parameters('sharepointonline_1_token:TenantId')]"
    }
  }
```

Could anyone give an explanation of "token:TenantId". How/where to get this value in my dev tenant. How this can be moved to UAT/PROD environment?

Whenever I recreate my logic app with the SharePoint connection it loses the connection and shows me below screen with a warning icon.

[image]

Is there a way we can authenticate this connection via PowerShell or via Azure DevOps deployment?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the SharePoint Online Tenant ID, although since the Logic App designer created that connection for you, you can probably find that value in the `.parameters` file in your project.  If it is not already there, then probably the easiest is described in [this blog](http://blog.scoreman.net/2013/02/create-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom/):

> Navigate to https://**yourtenantname**.sharepoint.com/_layouts/appprincipals.aspx. Identify the row with your registered application and look at the App Identifier column. The unique identifier after the @-sign in the App Identifier is the app realm. Copy the realm (not the whole App Identifier just the last part after the @-sign).

You can also get the Tenant ID [using powershell](https://knowledge-junction.com/2018/02/17/office-365-tenant-id/) by using the cmdlet `Login-AzureRmAccount`.

If you are attempting to deploy your Logic App using a DevOps pipeline, then you will want to grab that Tenant ID ahead of time and store it in a pipeline parameter variable.

Comment: Thanks @willman for the help. I have updated my parameter file with the tentnat id but the connection is still not authenticated. The only way I am able to authenticate is via Logic App Designer

Comment: How are you deploying your Logic App?  If you are deploying using the tools in Visual Studio, or if you are deploying from a DevOps pipeline, either one of those should use the json you posted in your question to generate an `API Connection` in Azure that your app will use.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have added parameter for tokenid in my parameter file. Currently, I am doing deployment with Visual Studio.

Comment: After deploying, can you view API Connections in your Azure Portal too see if it got created?

Comment: Its there but unauthorized.

Comment: I was able to authorize with PowerShell mentioned in below this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#authorize-oauth-connections

Comment: Once it is in Azure, you should be able to manually authorize it through the Azure Portal interface.  You only need to do this once, as long as your Logic App stays dependent on that API Connection, you won't have to re-authorize unless the password for the connection changes.  If you deploy a new Connect instance for Prod, you'll need to authorize that one after the first deployment too.

Comment: Thanks, Willman for the suggestion. Manually authentication is definitely an option but what I was looking for is to do the same via PowerShell